# access to struct field from struct method field

Tags: function, go, struct

How I can access struct field **Name** from struct method field **PrintName**
example:

```
type Data struct {
    Name      string
    PrintName func()
}

func main() {
    data := Data{
        Name: "Name",
        PrintName: func() {
            fmt.Println(Name)
        },
    }

    data.PrintName()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function value you assign to `Data.PrintName` has no connection to the enclosing struct whatsoever, so in the general case it can't access the `Name` field.

If you want to access the name field, you have to pass it explicitly, or use a closure that can access the `data` struct like this:

```
data := Data{
    Name: "Name",
}

data.PrintName = func() {
    fmt.Println(data.Name)
}

data.PrintName()
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/gOEkklJPFXv)):

```
Name
```

In this example the function value we assign to `data.PrintName` field is a *closure* because it uses a variable from the enclosing block.

You can also choose to pass the `Data` value explicitly to the function value, but then its signature must be modified:

```
type Data struct {
    Name      string
    PrintName func(d Data)
}

func main() {
    data := Data{
        Name: "Name",
    }

    data.PrintName = func(d Data) {
        fmt.Println(d.Name)
    }

    data.PrintName(data)
}
```

This outputs the same, try this one on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/-3IMFydVVxD).

Answer (score 1):

Is there any particular reason you want PrintName as a struct field instead of just a method of Data?

```
type Data struct {
    Name string
}
func (data *Data) PrintName(){
    fmt.Println(data.Name)
}
```